# Displaying titles of collapsed menus

Tags: 7, routes

I'm currently converting a mock-up and I need to display four menus in a list, the first two are expanded, and I need to display both the titles and menu items, and the next two are collapsed, so I need to display the titles but not the menu items. It should look something like this:

> Menu 1
>
> - Menu item 1
> - Menu item 2
> - Menu item 3
>
> Menu 2
>
> - Menu item 1
> - Menu item 2
> - Menu item 3
>
> Menu 3
>
> Menu 4

Is there an easy way to do that in Drupal's admin panel?

Comment: Currently your question is too ambiguous. Which version of Drupal? Which theme? Are the menus nested unordered lists? Are you using Superfish or Nice Menus? Finally, how one defines "easy" is as precise a descriptor as to whether vanilla or chocolate are the better ice cream flavor. I believe your question is salvageable but please provide more specifics.

Comment: Do your Menu 3 and Menu 4 items have specific IDs or classes? If so, what about using jQuery to collapse them upon page load?

Comment: Thank you, longboardnode, I'm not currently using any additional menu modules, but I will look into your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way to do this in Drupals admin panel is to set the menu titles as parent menu items and use "Show as expanded" settings (admin/structure/menu/item/yourmenuname/edit) and hide the menu-names with the block name settings (set to `<none>`)

[image]

Comment: not sure but might be http://drupal.org/project/menu_block,and http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu can be of some help here

Comment: Thanks, Volker, I will try your solution and get back to you!